# I don't know what else to put in the else sentence in these positions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

**what i can write in else statements without error or exceptions in this method**
this code write with java and used mongo db
i want add object from workOrder and check if null or not and i want check if the id is null or not but if the workOrder or id is null i dont know what i can return

```
    public TaskDataDTO save(TaskDataDTO taskDataDTO,String WorkOrderId) {
            if(WorkOrderId!=null) {
                taskDataDTO.setWorkOrderId(WorkOrderId);
                Optional<WorkOrderDTO> workOrderDTO=workOrderRepository.findById(WorkOrderId).map(workOrderMapper::toDto);
                if(workOrderDTO!=null)
                {
                    log.debug("Request to save TaskData : {}", taskDataDTO);
                    taskDataDTO.setWorkOrderDTO(workOrderDTO);
                    TaskData taskData = taskDataMapper.toEntity(taskDataDTO);
                    taskData = taskDataRepository.save(taskData);
                    return taskDataMapper.toDto(taskData);
                }
                else {
                    //what can i write here
                    
                }
                

            }
            else{
                //what can i write here
            }

}
```

Comment: Either wrap it in an `Optional` or throw an exception if you expect an entry in the database. Another option is to return `null` but that is discouraged

Comment: btw I would be VERY surprised if `workOrderDTO` is ever `null`, it may be not present, but an optional itself being null would be very, very bad style.

Comment: then what is the best practices in these case

Answer (score 2):

You will need to deal with Exceptions when you call the method, but this will be safer on your case:

```
public TaskDataDTO save(TaskDataDTO taskDataDTO,String WorkOrderId) throws Exception {
        if(WorkOrderId!=null) {
            taskDataDTO.setWorkOrderId(WorkOrderId);
            Optional<WorkOrderDTO> workOrderDTO=workOrderRepository.findById(WorkOrderId).map(workOrderMapper::toDto);
            if(workOrderDTO!=null)
            {
                log.debug("Request to save TaskData : {}", taskDataDTO);
                taskDataDTO.setWorkOrderDTO(workOrderDTO);
                TaskData taskData = taskDataMapper.toEntity(taskDataDTO);
                taskData = taskDataRepository.save(taskData);
                return taskDataMapper.toDto(taskData);
            }
            else {
                throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException("The work order was not found");
            }
            

        }
        else{
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("WorkOrderId cannot be null");
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

A Spring Data `CrudRepository` will never return `null` from `findById(ID)`. You'll always get an `Optional` that will either contain the entity with the matching ID or it will be empty. I would remove the `workOrderDTO != null` check completely.

If your `save` method requires a non-null `WorkOrderId`, I would assert this at the beginning of the method. For example, you could use `java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(WorkOrderId)`

These two changes simplify your code as there are now no branches. It would look something like this:

```
public TaskDataDTO save(TaskDataDTO taskDataDTO,String WorkOrderId) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(WorkOrderId);
    taskDataDTO.setWorkOrderId(WorkOrderId);
    Optional<WorkOrderDTO> workOrderDTO=workOrderRepository.findById(WorkOrderId).map(workOrderMapper::toDto);
    log.debug("Request to save TaskData : {}", taskDataDTO);
    taskDataDTO.setWorkOrderDTO(workOrderDTO);
    TaskData taskData = taskDataMapper.toEntity(taskDataDTO);
    taskData = taskDataRepository.save(taskData);
    return taskDataMapper.toDto(taskData);
}
```

This assumes that your `taskDataDTO` can deal with an empty `Optional` for the `workOrderDTO`. If it cannot, you may need an `ifPresent()` check. You may also want to consider passing `WorkOrderDTO` into the `TaskDataDTO` rather than an `Optional<WorkOrderDTO>`.